# How to let the docker container know itself is running with a host network?

Tags: docker

My container must be running in host network model (--net=host), so I want the container to stop and report a error if it is not running in a host network.
How can I do it in some script,which is running in the container?

Comment: can you elaborate? I am not sure I understand what you want to do and why.

Comment: I mean I want run some script in the container, and it will be ran in the container,  then the container can check whether itself is running at host network model., if not,, print some log message and exit.

Comment: mount the docker socket, `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` so your container will be able to `docker inspect` or any other docker command, and check if `--net=host` was used while launching the container

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the solution works.

1. Run your container with -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
2. Download docker from
   https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest.tgz
3. tar xf ./docker-latest.tgz
4. docker cp ./docker/docker :/usr/bin/
5. docker exec  /usr/bin/docker inspect  | grep NetworkMode| awk -F '"' '{print $4;}'
6. Get the network type result: host